# Words unique to a user - where not in

Tags: sql, mysql, postgresql

I have a very simple table structure here.  Just a list of words related to a simple user_id.

```
Word Table: 
    word - varchar(50)
    user_id - integer
```

I need to find words used by one user that are not used by other users.  Currently I'm doing this and it works alright on Postgresql (9.0.3) at 200k words (~.3-.5 seconds) and completely falls over on MySQL (5.1.54) with the same data (5+ mins and it is still running).   All used columns are indexed.

```
SELECT  
    word, count(word) as count
FROM 
    words
WHERE         
    word not in (select word from words where user_id <> 99 group by word)
    and user_id = 99
GROUP BY word
ORDER BY count desc LIMIT 20
```

1) Anyone know of a better way to do this?

2) Anyone know why it is completely failing on MySql?

**EDIT:  This fixes the issue on MySQL, from 5 mins+ to 10-20ms - Thanks Borealid**

```
SELECT  
    word, count(word) as count
FROM 
    words
WHERE         
    word not in (select distinct word from words where user_id <> 99)
    and user_id = 99
GROUP BY word
ORDER BY count desc LIMIT 20
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using `SELECT DISTINCT word FROM words` instead of the `GROUP BY word`?

Comment: Oh, on the sub-select.  I'll give that a shot.

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks.  That fixed it on MySQL.  Eliminated the choking completely.  It is far faster than PG with the same query now.  PG must have a better optimizer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try NOT EXISTS():

```
SELECT  
    w1.word, 
    COUNT(w1.word) as count
FROM 
    words w1
WHERE         
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM 
            words w2 
        WHERE 
            w2.user_id <> 99 
        AND 
            w1.word = w2.word 
        )
AND 
    w1.user_id = 99
GROUP BY 
    w1.word
ORDER BY 
    count DESC 
LIMIT 20;
```

Make sure you have an index on the user_id and word (or a combination), use explain to see the queryplan and what works best for you.

======
Edit: Also try the LEFT JOIN solution using a IS NULL:

```
SELECT
    w1.word,
    COUNT(w1.word) AS count
FROM
    words w1
        LEFT JOIN words w2 ON (w1.word = w2.word AND w1.user_id <> w2.user_id)
WHERE
    w1.user_id = 99
AND
    w2.word IS NULL
GROUP BY
    w1.word
ORDER BY 
    count DESC 
LIMIT 20;
```

Try an index on both columns:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_word_user ON words ( word, user_id);
```

Comment: This is a nice alt solution.  Need to do further test but, seems to be slightly faster on both.

Comment: Your fist solution is really good.  44ms for my base-line, 18ms for your first solution vs 166ms on your second solution.  The second one completely chokes on MySQL like my first attempt.  Touchy touch huh?

Comment: MySQL has less options to do it's job, that's why it fails in many cases when executing a bit more complex queries. EXISTS is optimized in many dbms's, that why it's fast on most of them, including PostgreSQL and MySQL. 18ms sounds like cache, check EXPLAIN to get the queryplan. A cold start of your database, to be sure there is nothing in cache, can show the performance when there is no data in cache.